# AF:table how to prevent SelectionEvent on escape button

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an `af:table` inside `af:popup` .The following is the steps to reproduce my issue.

1. Display af:popup
2. I have some data displayed in table
3. Select one row in the table.Now the focus is on table
4. if I press ESC the popup is getting closed and also a SelectionEvent is triggered.This SelectionEvent will clear the table selected rows.
5. Next time when I open the popup again the table displayed as none of the rows selected.

I want to persist the table selection information even if the popup 
    is closed but it is working properly if I click on popup close
    button but not working when I press `ESC`.

Answer (score 0):

In PopupCanceled Listener(Through Bean) use the same logic you use for Selection Event.

Comment: SelectionEvent is being thrown whenever I press the esc(to close the popup).My question is is there any way (in adf not JavaScript)to prevent the selection event on pressing of escape key .

Comment: Cancel through Bean. you can refresh the Popup in Bean through Cancel Listener, So even if its get called, no use.

Comment: IT should work-->     public void onCancel(PopupCanceledEvent popupCanceledEvent) {
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(popupBind);
    }

Comment: I don't want to suppress the CancelEvent I want to suppress  the SelectionEvent

Comment: I dont think there is any direct way to do that. If you do as i mentioned, it will refresh the Table. So you no need to worry about selection. Try that and let me know